# Get current time as formatted string in Go?

Tags: timestamp, go

What's the best way to get the current timestamp in Go and convert to string? I need both date and time in eg. YYYYMMDDhhmmss format.

Comment: This is all you need https://www.golangprograms.com/get-current-date-and-time-in-various-format-in-golang.html

Answer (score 177, accepted):

Use the [`time.Now()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now) function and the [`time.Format()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) method.

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format("20060102150405"))
```

prints out `20110504111515`, or at least it did a few minutes ago. (I'm on Eastern Daylight Time.) There are several pre-defined time formats in the [constants](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants) defined in the time package.

You can use [`time.Now().UTC()`](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.UTC) if you'd rather have UTC than your local time zone.

Comment: I definitely like the `Kitchen` constant (`= "3:04PM"`)

Comment: Thanks for that info. How does the time package know from passing "20060102150405", just what we are passing, as it is not one of the pre-defined constants in the time package? What is the significance of that date and time in the time package (20060102150405)? It seems a little bit quirky to me, but as long as it works I suppose it doesn't matter as long as we don't make an error when coding it. I guess they didn't see fit to provide a constant for that format, and match the string pattern.

Comment: @brianoh: See http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Constants It is the time "01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700" Because each component has a different number (1, 2, 3, etc.), it can determine from the numbers what components you want.

Comment: Please note that time.LocalTime() doesn't exist anymore : see my answer below to be Go 1.0.3 compatible

Comment: It's very strange that I have to remember a number that much less than my wife's birthday!  Do you think GO constant is much important than your families' birthday? why not just '%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S‘ ？

Comment: @Siwei don't ask. It was most certainly one of those weirdnesses that exist since the dawn of time (pun intended)...

Answer (score 86):

All the other response are very miss-leading for somebody coming from google and looking for "timestamp in go"! YYYYMMDDhhmmss is not a "timestamp".

To get the "timestamp" of a date in go (number of seconds from january 1970), the correct function is [Time.Unix()](https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix), and it really return an integer

Comment: I agree; the question should be titled "current date" not "current timestamp"

Comment: Although it is late, i think .Unix() should point to https://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Unix whose return type is int64.

Comment: While you are technically correct, I think a lot of coders these days conflate timestamp with, 'The current time in some sort of formatted fashion', so that title would be equally confusing to most.

Comment: I have suggested an edit - `Get current time as formatted string in Go?`. Hopefully someone will approve it.

Answer (score 77):

For readability, best to use the RFC constants in the time package (me thinks)

```
import "fmt" 
import "time"

func main() {
    fmt.Println(time.Now().Format(time.RFC850))
}
```

Comment: How does this produce YYYYMMDDhhmmss ?

Comment: RFC850 produces `Tuesday, 10-Nov-09 23:00:00 UTC` 
`RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"` 

https://play.golang.org/p/XmobwWSz5pN
https://golang.org/pkg/time/

Comment: I personally prefer: `time.Now().Format(time.RFC3339)`, sample output: `2021-08-19T13:52:51+03:00`

Answer (score 36):

Use the [time.Now()](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Now) and [time.Format()](http://golang.org/pkg/time/#Time.Format) functions (as time.LocalTime() doesn't exist anymore as of Go 1.0.3)

```
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format("20060102150405"))
```

[Online demo](http://play.golang.org/p/pswRw8DGqN)  (with date fixed in the past in the playground, never mind)

Comment: And you can use it simply as a string like this: ```s := "Actual time is: "+time.Now().String()```

Answer (score 14):

Find more info in this post: [Get current date and time in various format in golang](https://www.golangprograms.com/get-current-date-and-time-in-various-format-in-golang.html)

This is a taste of the different formats that you'll find:

```golang
package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
)

func main() {
    currentTime := time.Now()
    fmt.Println("Current Time in String: ", currentTime.String())
    fmt.Println("MM-DD-YYYY : ", currentTime.Format("01-02-2006"))
    fmt.Println("YYYY-MM-DD : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02"))
    fmt.Println("YYYY.MM.DD : ", currentTime.Format("2006.01.02 15:04:05"))
    fmt.Println("YYYY#MM#DD {Special Character} : ", currentTime.Format("2006#01#02"))
    fmt.Println("YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05"))
    fmt.Println("Time with MicroSeconds: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000"))
    fmt.Println("Time with NanoSeconds: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05.000000000"))
    fmt.Println("ShortNum Month : ", currentTime.Format("2006-1-02"))
    fmt.Println("LongMonth : ", currentTime.Format("2006-January-02"))
    fmt.Println("ShortMonth : ", currentTime.Format("2006-Jan-02"))
    fmt.Println("ShortYear : ", currentTime.Format("06-Jan-02"))
    fmt.Println("LongWeekDay : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 15:04:05 Monday"))
    fmt.Println("ShortWeek Day : ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 Mon"))
    fmt.Println("ShortDay : ", currentTime.Format("Mon 2006-01-2"))
    fmt.Println("Short Hour Minute Second: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 3:4:5"))
    fmt.Println("Short Hour Minute Second: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 3:4:5 PM"))
    fmt.Println("Short Hour Minute Second: ", currentTime.Format("2006-01-02 3:4:5 pm"))
}
```

The output is:

```
Current Time in String:  2017-07-04 00:47:20.1424751 +0530 IST
MM-DD-YYYY :  07-04-2017
YYYY-MM-DD :  2017-07-04
YYYY.MM.DD :  2017.07.04 00:47:20
YYYY#MM#DD {Special Character} :  2017#07#04
YYYY-MM-DD hh:mm:ss :  2017-07-04 00:47:20
Time with MicroSeconds:  2017-07-04 00:47:20.142475
Time with NanoSeconds:  2017-07-04 00:47:20.142475100
ShortNum Month :  2017-7-04
LongMonth :  2017-July-04
ShortMonth :  2017-Jul-04
ShortYear :  17-Jul-04
LongWeekDay :  2017-07-04 00:47:20 Tuesday
ShortWeek Day :  2017-07-04 Tue
ShortDay :  Tue 2017-07-4
Short Hour Minute Second:  2017-07-04 12:47:20
Short Hour Minute Second:  2017-07-04 12:47:20 AM
Short Hour Minute Second:  2017-07-04 12:47:20 am
```

Comment: Please post code as code, not as pictures.

Answer (score 3):

https://golang.org/src/time/format.go specified 
For parsing time `15` is used for Hours, `04` is used for minutes, `05` for seconds.

For parsing Date `11`, `Jan`, `January` is for months, `02`, `Mon`, `Monday` for Day of the month, `2006` for year and of course `MST` for zone

But you can use this layout as well, which I find very simple. `"Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006"`

```golang
    const layout = "Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
    userTimeString := "Fri Dec 6 13:05:05 CET 2019"

    t, _ := time.Parse(layout, userTimeString)
    fmt.Println("Server: ", t.Format(time.RFC850))
    //Server:  Friday, 06-Dec-19 13:05:05 CET

    mumbai, _ := time.LoadLocation("Asia/Kolkata")
    mumbaiTime := t.In(mumbai)
    fmt.Println("Mumbai: ", mumbaiTime.Format(time.RFC850))
    //Mumbai:  Friday, 06-Dec-19 18:35:05 IST
```

[DEMO](https://play.golang.org/p/92oWW6jnsH6)

Answer (score 2):

You can simply use like ***strconv.Itoa(int(time.Now().Unix()))***

Answer (score 1):

As an echo to @Bactisme's response, the way one would go about retrieving the current timestamp (in milliseconds, for example) is:

```
msec := time.Now().UnixNano() / 1000000
```

Resource: https://gobyexample.com/epoch

Comment: `time.Now().UnixMilli()`

Answer (score -4):

To answer the exact question:

```
import "github.com/golang/protobuf/ptypes"

Timestamp, _ = ptypes.TimestampProto(time.Now())
```

Comment: Thanks Suran, this is useful when the time stamp needs to be send across grpc