# What does 20060102150405 mean?

Tags: go

I would like to get current time value. I found [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5885486/how-do-i-get-the-current-timestamp-in-go/5885753) answer which works for me but don't know why format method take `20060102150405` value? Not like `yyyyMMdd hhmmss`.

Comment: `2006-01-02 15:04:05`?

Answer (score 15):

Go's time formatting unique and different than what you would do in other languages. Instead of having a conventional format to print the date, Go uses the reference date `20060102150405` which seems meaningless but actually has a reason, as it's `1 2 3 4 5 6` in the Posix `date` command:

```
Mon Jan 2 15:04:05 -0700 MST 2006
0   1   2  3  4  5              6
```

The timezone is `7` but that sits in the middle, so in the end the format resembles `1 2 3 4 5 7 6`.

[This online converter](https://web.archive.org/web/20180321052610/http://fuckinggodateformat.com/) is handy, if you are transitioning from the `strftime` format.

Interesting historical reference: https://github.com/golang/go/issues/444

The `time` package provides handy constants as well:

```golang
const (
        ANSIC       = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 2006"
        UnixDate    = "Mon Jan _2 15:04:05 MST 2006"
        RubyDate    = "Mon Jan 02 15:04:05 -0700 2006"
        RFC822      = "02 Jan 06 15:04 MST"
        RFC822Z     = "02 Jan 06 15:04 -0700" // RFC822 with numeric zone
        RFC850      = "Monday, 02-Jan-06 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123     = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 MST"
        RFC1123Z    = "Mon, 02 Jan 2006 15:04:05 -0700" // RFC1123 with numeric zone
        RFC3339     = "2006-01-02T15:04:05Z07:00"
        RFC3339Nano = "2006-01-02T15:04:05.999999999Z07:00"
        Kitchen     = "3:04PM"
        // Handy time stamps.
        Stamp      = "Jan _2 15:04:05"
        StampMilli = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000"
        StampMicro = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000"
        StampNano  = "Jan _2 15:04:05.000000000"
)
```

You can use them like this:

```golang
t := time.Now()
fmt.Println(t.Format(time.ANSIC))
```

Answer (score 4):

See https://golang.org/pkg/time/#pkg-constants It is the time "01/02 03:04:05PM '06 -0700" Because each component has a different number (1, 2, 3, etc.), it can determine from the numbers what components you want.

Answer (score 1):

20060102150405 is a date and time format 2006/01/02 15:04:05

package main

import (
    "fmt"
    "time"
    )

func main() {

```
date1 := time.Now().Format("2006/01/02 15:04")
fmt.Println(date1)//2009/11/10 23:00

date2 := time.Now().Format("20060102150405")
fmt.Println(date2)//20091110230000
```

}

https://play.golang.org/p/kIfNRQ50JP